# R: rollapply on two variables

Tags: r, xts

I am trying to do rollapply on two columns in a dataframe

```
library(xts)
library("dLagM")

data(warming)
fdlm1 <- function(){
model.ardl = ardlDlm(x = warming$NoMotorVehicles, y = warming$Warming, p = 1 , q = 1 , show.summary = FALSE)

fc <- ardlDlmForecast(model = model.ardl , x = tail(x,1) , h =1)$forecasts
fc
return(fc)}

dcalc1 <- rollapply(warming,18,fdlm1)
```

However is get an error:

```
Error in FUN(data[posns], ...) : unused argument (data[posns])
```

Thank you for any help in pointing out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `rollapply` calls the function on each column of the data, individually.  You need to set `by.column = FALSE` if you want the function to have access to more than one column.

```
dcalc1 <- rollapply(warming, 18, fdlm1, by.column = FALSE)
```

---

This simple example works:

```
data(sample_matrix)
x <- as.xts(sample_matrix)
r <- rollapply(x, 40, function(d) coef(lm(Close ~ Open, data=d)), by.column=FALSE)
```

If you still have problems, then I would address two issues I see with your function:

1. You should pass objects to your function via arguments instead of
   relying on scoping to find them, and
2. `x` in `tail(x, 1)` is not defined in the function scope... so it's hard to say where R is finding a value for `x`.

Comment: Then the problem is likely with your function, because a simple example works: `data(sample_matrix); x <- as.xts(sample_matrix); rollapply(x, 40, function(d) coef(lm(Close ~ Open, data=d)), by.column=FALSE)`.  You really should pass objects to your function via arguments instead of relying on scoping to find them.  And `x` in `tail(x, 1)` is not defined in the function scope... so it's hard to say where R is finding a value for `x`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.